# How to list all available versions of a certain package?

Tags: apt

apt-cache dump returns all information of available packages. In order to get all versions of a certain package the following was tried:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ apt-cache dump | grep -A25 "python-bottle-doc" | grep Version
 Version: 0.12.7-1+deb8u1build0.16.04.1
 Version: 0.12.7-1
```

but this is not a stable solution as some packages possesses less details then others.

Comment: Try `apt-cache policy <packagename>`. It will return multiple versions only if the package is available in multiple repositories...or if you are late in upgrading to repo version. This is an unusual question - why do you ask?

Comment: `Aptitude` also list all available version in the package descriptions. though usually there are only one or two, unless multiple repositories are enabled